# How to set channel when sending a notification from Firebase to an Android device?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

After setting the Notification Channels on an Android app, and having most notifications being sent from a backend system, how do you set a notification's channel from the backend?

If the notification payload being sent from the backend is:

```
  "message": {
    "topic" : "foo-bar",
    "notification": {
      "body": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title": "FCM Message"
    }
  }
```

then where should the channel be added ?

Comment: Ask the backend guys to send the notification in data block not notification block, so that you can retrieve the data block in every scenario. Once you get the data in the "data" block retrieve the notification channel from the "data" block and check which channel it matches to in your android app. Accordingly set the notification channel to that particular notification.

Comment: That would be one way to do it, but I'm sure there's a solution while still using the notification body (?)

Comment: I've solved this for me by changing the payload from the backend, but I'll leave the question open.

Comment: Using data block and stuff?

Comment: Yes, sending a data notification (i.e. invisible and reacheble on the firebase service) instead of an actual notification that goes to the system tray.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [`android_channel_id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support):

> The notification's [channel id](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-channels.html) (new in Android O).
>
> The app must create a channel with this ID before any notification with this key is received.
>
> If you don't send this key in the request, or if the channel id provided has not yet been created by your app, FCM uses the channel id specified in your app manifest.

Comment: Passing this key doesn't seem to work, notifications still land as "uncategorised".

Comment: I suggest posting your code on how you're handling the payload, in order for the community to post better answers.

Comment: I'm using s library to handle notifications (django-push-notifications) which makes it very difficult to post the relevant code here.

Comment: Be sure you add android_channel_id inside the notification object.